# Change email address when it is username field

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm using django-allauth for my user management and using the user's email address as the username field.

Everything is working fine and I've got a form the user can use to update their details - first name, last name etc. - which works perfectly.

But it won't update the user's email address using that form. I'm guessing it's because it's the primary key but how would I go about allowing the user to change their email address in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [EmailAddress.change](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/models.py#L61) in your view.